# How to get output of list

Tags: c#, list, class, sorting

```
        LicnaKarta osoba1 = new LicnaKarta("Petar", "Petrovic", "05051999800015", "Novi Sad", 
        new DateTime(1999, 05, 05), new Adresa("Vidovdanska", "5A"));
        LicnaKarta osoba2 = new LicnaKarta("Marko", "Markovic", "06061998800015", "Beograd", new DateTime(1998, 06, 06), new Adresa("Rusinska", "66"));
        LicnaKarta osoba3 = new LicnaKarta("Ana", "Ivanovic", "07071997800015", "Beograd", new DateTime(1997, 07, 07), new Adresa("Svetozara Miletica", "1B"));
        LicnaKarta osoba4 = new LicnaKarta("Boris", "Radukic", "08081996800015", "Zemun", new DateTime(1996, 08, 08), new Adresa("Milosa Crnjanskog", "8"));
        LicnaKarta osoba5 = new LicnaKarta("Milica", "Pavlovic", "09091995800015", "Nis", new DateTime(1995, 09, 09), new Adresa("Laze Nancica", "22"));

        List<DateTime> redjanje = new List<DateTime>();
        redjanje.Add(osoba1.datumrodjenja);
        redjanje.Add(osoba2.datumrodjenja);
        redjanje.Add(osoba3.datumrodjenja);
        redjanje.Add(osoba4.datumrodjenja);
        redjanje.Add(osoba5.datumrodjenja);
        redjanje.Sort();
        foreach (var item in redjanje)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        List<LicnaKarta> konacnalista = new List<LicnaKarta>();
        konacnalista.Add(osoba1);
        konacnalista.Add(osoba2);
        konacnalista.Add(osoba3);
        konacnalista.Add(osoba4);
        konacnalista.Add(osoba5);
        foreach (var item in konacnalista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

I sort DateTime with List. And Output is date i write. But i cant output and other things like Petar,Petrovic and other things.Someone can help?

Comment: i forget to say that LicnaKarta is class

Comment: The first for each loop will display the date only coz `redjanje` is a list of dates. What output do you get from the second for each loop ?

Comment: Didnt get anything. I try to get all this informations but from the oldest person to younger

Comment: What does `LicnaKarta` look like?

Answer (score 0):

`console.writeline(item.firstname)` or `console.writeline(item.date)` (or what ever you call these properties in "LicnaKarta").

The "item" in the for loop is the object LicnaKarta with properties if the values you set at the top of the code snippet.  You can reference them by calling item.date for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Reflection** like that

```
foreach (var item in konacnalista)
{
   foreach(var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties()) {
       Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item, null));
   }
}
```